# How do get individual words from a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

How do I convert something like:

```
const char phrase[] = "this is my phrase";
```

into something like:

```
char a[0] = "this";
char a[1] = "is";
char a[2] = "my";
char a[3] = "phrase";
```

Can I use pointers to access the words rather than the characters in a char array?

Comment: Get rid of the `const` qualifier, and use `strtok`. Either that, or make a copy of the array, and use `strtok`.

Comment: any chance I can do it without using strtok?

Comment: You can write a loop that does the same thing, by looking at each character separately to see if it's a space `' '`, or the newline `'\n'` or the NUL terminator `'\0'`